# How resolve error "Some or all identity references could not be translated" returned by DevOps 2019 console administration

Tags: windows, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm using windows server 2016 and Azure DevOps Server 2019 update 1.1.

I succesfully configured two trusted domain A and B. In DevOps console administration (installed on a server in domain A), when I try to add a user (from domain B), I obtain the error described below.

- check name properly works:

[image]

- but when I click on "Ok" to confirm user addition I obtain following error:

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: The error message means the account couldn't be found. Please verify the affected account. Please also try other user accounts to check if they have the same issue. If all the users have the same issue, then it should be a domain trust issue.

Comment: Is thene any official documentation provided by Microsoft about use of DevOps with trusted domain? Otherwise, is there any official documentation provided by Microsoft about setting trusted domain with windows server 2016?

Comment: Didn't find the official documentation about that. However find a blog talking about that, hope that helps: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/trusts-and-forests-considerations-for-team-foundation-server/ . And another blog for your reference : https://windowstechpro.com/active-directory-trust-relationship-between-two-domains-in-server-2016/